# C# Building Expressions in Linq-to-Entities, Searching all properties' string representations in a type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities, expression

I'm trying to build a dynamic LINQ-to-Entities query builder to return filter expressions using property names as strings, or expressions that check all properties in the type. If the property is an integer I want to check if it is equal to the search value, otherwise I want to see if the string value of the property contains the search value.

The builder has two methods: one that returns the lambda expression when passed the property name as a string and the search value, and one that checks all properties within that type against the search value.

For searching against a single property, I have the following:

```
    public static Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> GetFilter<TEntity>(string data, string propertyName)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity));
        Type t = typeof(TEntity).GetProperty(propertyName).PropertyType;
        var property = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, propertyName);
        ConstantExpression constant;
        Expression predicate;



        if (t == typeof(int))
        {
            int temp;
            bool check = int.TryParse(data, out temp);

            if (!check)
            {
                return ((TEntity x) => false);
            }

            constant = Expression.Constant(temp);


            predicate = Expression.Call(property, "Equals", null, constant);
        }
        else
        {
            constant = Expression.Constant(data);
            var toString = Expression.Call(property, "ToString", null);

            predicate = Expression.Call(toString, "Contains", null, constant);



        }


        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(predicate, parameter);

    }
```

This works perfectly. However, when trying to do this with all properties, I get a NotSupportedException, stating that ToString() cannot be converted to a valid SQL query.

To set the expression, I have a temporary Expression called exp, and the code that sets it is exactly the same. I then 'concatenate' the expressions by calling Expression.Or()

```
    public static Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> GetFilterForAll<TEntity>(string data)
    {

        Type t = typeof(TEntity);
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(t);

        var properties = from p in t.GetProperties()
                         where p.CanRead && !p.GetGetMethod().IsVirtual && p.Name.ToLower() != "id"
                         select Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, p.Name);


        Expression predicate = null;

        foreach (var prop in properties)
        {
            ConstantExpression constant;


            Expression exp;

            if (prop.Type == typeof(int))
            {
                int temp;
                bool check = int.TryParse(data, out temp);

                if (!check)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                constant = Expression.Constant(temp);


                exp = Expression.Call(prop, "Equals", null, constant);
            }
            else
            {
                constant = Expression.Constant(data);
                var toString = Expression.Call(prop, "ToString", null);

                exp = Expression.Call(toString, "Contains", null, constant);


            }



            if (predicate == null)
            {
                predicate = exp;
            }
            else
            {
                predicate = Expression.Or(predicate, exp);
            }

        }

        if (predicate == null) return null;

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(predicate, parameter);

    }
```

I know I'm going wrong somewhere, especially as this has all been learnt today, and I suspect it's how I'm doing the 'Or' expressions.

Comment: Have you seen PredicateBuilder?  It will probably help with the `Or`:  http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Comment: I'll have a look. I'd been at this for about 6 hours or so when I decided to post and my mind was mush.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this without ***Equals*** because doesn't in the scope and i will need create some attr or flag to set what prop will be filtered ***Exactly*** or ***Likely***, and i just go 1 level in depth of the navigations, so maybe this can help you to understand:

```
private static readonly MethodInfo ToStringMethod = typeof(object).GetMethod("ToString");
private static readonly MethodInfo StringContainsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains");

public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> BuildFilterPredicate<T>(string q)
{
    var query = Expression.Constant(q);
    var type = typeof(T);
    var lambdaParam = Expression.Parameter(type);
    var predicates = type.GetProperties().SelectMany(p => PredicateContainsBuilder(lambdaParam, p, query)).ToList();
    Expression body = predicates[0];
    body = predicates.Skip(1).Aggregate(body, Expression.OrElse);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, lambdaParam);
}

private static IEnumerable<MethodCallExpression> PredicateContainsBuilder(Expression lambdaParam, PropertyInfo prop, Expression query)
{

    if (prop.PropertyType.IsClass)
        return new List<MethodCallExpression> { Expression.Call(Expression.Call(Expression.Property(lambdaParam, prop), ToStringMethod), StringContainsMethod, query) };

    var properties = prop.PropertyType.GetProperties();
    return properties.Select(p => Expression.Call(Expression.Call(Expression.Property(lambdaParam, p), ToStringMethod), StringContainsMethod, query)).ToList();
}
```

try to use `OrElse` instead of `Or`

Comment: While the exact code didn't work (especially the last bit where you iterate through the property's properties), the main bit of aggregating the predicates worked like a dream. I've refactored for it to return single MethodCallExpressions, use int.Equals() for integer properties, and have refactored my single-property method to use PredicateContainsBuilder().